# How do I reuse Typescript React Components in multiple projects?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm

I want to create an npm package that includes multiple react components that use typescript. I'm pretty new to react and npm so sorry if this is obvious. I've had a look online I couldn't find much on this topic. I'm not bothered about the package being hosted by npm it would be easier if it was just a local package. I would appreciate any help you can offer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can create your project with reusable components:

```
mkdir my-reusable-components && cd my-reusable components
```

[Initiate git](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-init):

```
git init
```

[Initiate npm](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/init) package

```
npm init
```

Optionally you can use [`npm link`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link) in your working directory and then in the dependant-project dir:

```
npm link my-reusable-components
```

Optionally before publishing to npm you can install your project from git

```
npm install <git repo url>
```